# Is there a way to add custom properties in the property panel for custom shapes?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

When I create a custom shape, I would like to add custom properties in the Property panel to update the shape, like for this one:

[image]

I know it is possible to create a new shape like this one:
[image]

I already followed these tutorials:

https://www.drawio.com/doc/faq/custom-shapes

https://www.drawio.com/doc/faq/shape-complex-create-edit

https://www.drawio.com/blog/shape-properties#view-the-shape-properties